# Правильно ли с точки зрения русского языка - "кандидат в члены клуба"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли с точки зрения русского языка построена фраза "кандидат в члены клуба"? Какие есть еще варианты?

Comment: У русского языка нет точки зрения.

Answer (score 3):

Не вижу во фразе никаких ошибок. Существует созданное аналогичным образом звание,  "кандидат в мастера спорта".

Answer (score 1):

Что может быть лучше "кандидата в члены клуба"? Наверное, только просто кандидат. Каких у нас только нет кандидатов - имеются, например, даже "кандидаты в члены гильдии театральных менеджеров России".

Просто кандидатами в Древней Спарте называли юношей, прошедших военную подготовку, когда их начинали считать готовыми воинами, потенциальными защитниками страны. В дореволюционной России тоже были просто кандидаты - студенты, окончившие юридические факультеты и зачисленные на должность, но еще официально не вступившие в нее.

ДЛЯ СПРАВОК

У этого слова есть близкие по значению слова "соискатель, претендент", но они значительно отличаются по смыслу.

КАНДИДАТ, 1.Тот, кто намечен для избрания, назначения , для получения чего-л. и т.п. К. в депутаты Городского собрания. Кандидаты на получение стипендии.2. чего. В СССР и России: младшая учёная степень,  К. технических наук. 3. В России до 80-х гг. 19 в.: младшая учёная степень, присваивавшаяся окончившему высшее учебное заведение с отличием; Кончить курс кандидатом.

ПРЕТЕНДЕНТ. Тот, кто претендует на что-л., предъявляет права на обладание чем-л. П. на освободившуюся должность. П. на звание чемпиона.

СОИСКАТЕЛЬ. Тот, кто претендует на получение звания, награды и т.п. за представленный куда-л. труд. С. учёной степени.